# custom behaviour to iphone addressbook ui controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, addressbook

is there any way to customize the ABPeoplePickerNavigationController and let user select multiple contacts without going into details? I can push contacts into an array as user selects them but there's no way to give visual feedback back to user that he/she selected the contacts he clicked (or unselect them on second click). 
I don't want to roll my own AB just for this simple feature.
As a workaround, can I display a custom modal view on top of Iphone AB UI?

Comment: There's no way to customize this. I ended up writing my own.

Answer (score 1):

you can used abcontact class.

```
    NSArray *collection = (aTableView == tableView) ? self.contacts : self.filteredArray;
    ABContact *contact = [collection objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   cell.textLabel.text = contact.contactName;
   cell.detailTextLabel.text=contact.phonenumbers;
   cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;
```

and on didselect row do this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{   

    NSArray *collection = (aTableView == self.tableView) ? self.contacts : self.filteredArray;
    ABContact *contact = [collection objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
```